# I Am Unable to stop my Alarm using stop button, I could only start it

Tags: java, android, alarm, audio-player

each time i enters seconds after alarm should start then click start button then when i want to stop it it won't happen .

below is my Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity7">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="start"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is my Activity file

```
package com.example.implementation;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity7 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1, button2;
    EditText et1;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main7);

        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startAlert();
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stopAlert();
            }
        });

    }

    private void startAlert() {
        int i = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("j", "1");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void stopAlert() {
        Intent stopIntent = new Intent();
        stopIntent.setAction("com.example.implementation.STOP_ALARM");
        sendBroadcast(stopIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    }

}
```

here is my brodcastreciver class file

```
package com.example.implementation;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && action.equals("com.example.implementation.STOP_ALARM")) {
            stopAlarm();
        } else {
            String jValue = intent.getStringExtra("j");
            if (jValue != null && jValue.equals("1")) {
                startAlarm(context);
            }
        }
    }

    private void startAlarm(Context context) {
        // Start the alarm (play sound or perform other actions)
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.audio1);
        mp.start();
        Log.d("MyBroadcastReceiver", "Alarm started");
    }

    private void stopAlarm() {
        // Stop the alarm (if it's playing)
        if (mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
            mp.stop();
        }
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
        Log.d("MyBroadcastReceiver", "Alarm stopped");
    }
}
```

this is my mainfest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Implementation"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity7"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity6"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity1"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity5"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity4"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity3"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.implementation.CUSTOM_ALARM_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I Have Pushed Both Chat gpt and Bard To Their limits But problem isn't solving. I I came to a conclusion that My receiver is not receiving broadcast .